# how to know whether an .apk can be reverse engineered in android

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, proguard

Hi friends I got to know that there is a website in which when we give our apk file it will say whether it can be simply reverse engineered or harder to reverse engineer when we applied reverse engineering.But i goggled a lot but I couldn't find that website can you please tell me about that website.

Comment: Everything can be reengineered. It's just a question of the resources you are willing to spend. I wouldn't trust such a site.

Comment: no whenever we implement proguard to our project it will be some difficult to do reverse engineer

Comment: Proguard makes it *harder* but not *impossible* to reverse engineer.

Comment: okay then i ned to edit the question with a bit difference

Comment: you can use decompilers

Comment: okay I will try to use them thanq

Answer (score 1):

Each .apk is reversible you just need the right tool.

Try to look into the xda developers forums,
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1910873